# Global value becomes null in method

Tags: java, android

I have created a private member of the whole class called `Member curMbr;`
The activity (rather the fragment, since this is in a frament class) has a listview
with some contributions from members. 
I also have a context menu on that list. When clicking on a contribution, I want a (customized) dialog box to show details about the member. (Member ID is part of the contribution objet. )

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    Log.d("FRGCOTIZ02", "create ctxt menu");

    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;
    String[] menuItems = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.ar_menu_ctxt_participant);
    // Get selected member
    Contribution  curCotis = (Contribution) (((ListView)v).getItemAtPosition(info.position));
    Participant p        = new Participant(helper.getDBItem(DBHelper.TABLE_PARTICIPANT,
                                DBHelper.COL_ID,    curCotis.getParticipant()));

    curMbr = new Member(helper.getDBItem(DBHelper.TABLE_MEMBER, DBHelper.COL_ID, p.getMember()));
    for (int i = 0; i < menuItems.length; i++) {
        menu.add(Menu.NONE, i, i, menuItems[i]);
    }
    Log.d("FRGCOTIZ01", curMbr.getId_());

}


@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    return (  applyContextMenuSelection(item) || super.onContextItemSelected(item) );
}

private boolean applyContextMenuSelection(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case 0: // Summary
            final Dialog dlg  = new Dialog(this.getContext());
            final String sessID;
            try {
                sessID = KUtil.DATE_FORMAT.format(curSess.getDate());
                dlg.setContentView(R.layout.alert_show_charges);
                Button btnOK = dlg.findViewById(R.id.btn_alertOK);
                btnOK.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        setupAlertDialogCharges(dlg, sessID, curMbr.getId_());
                    }
                });
                Button btnCancel = dlg.findViewById(R.id.btn_alertCancel);
                btnCancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        dlg.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                dlg.show();
            } catch (Exception e){
                Log.d("FRAGMENT Contribution", e.getMessage());
            }

            break;
        case 1: // Collect
            break;
        case 2: // Cancel
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

In method `onCreateContextMenu`, I can get the member and display his ID.
But in method `applyContextMenuSelection`, there is an exception, saying the meber is null!
Funny enough there is another variable that I am using in that method, and it works fine. Difference is, that variable has been set at creation of the fragment.
How do I solve this?

Comment: follow the flow of your code (debug it) and check that the value is indeed set for that instance of the class. Java doesn't have global variables, so I'm just assuming you are talking about instance variables.

Comment: @Stultuske Sorry, What I meant was a member of the class, which is supposed to be accessed by all methods. 

Regarding the flow, I even put some logs on the console to see the flow. When I set the value of member, I can get its ID on the console. The log specifing the beginning of method `applyContextMenuSelection` comes after. At this time, value of `curMbr` is `null`

Comment: it's certainly not that android sets the value automatically back to `null`. Is there any other code you've put that reads `curMbr = null`? Or anything else that assigns a new value? Like even later, e.g. `onPause` or so

Comment: @PhoenixBlue are you sure it's the same instance?

Comment: @Stultuske I declared that object only once and compilation gives no problem. So even if I didn't check properly, that should tell me it's the same instance! I think...

Comment: @PhoenixBlue declaring a variable is not the same as instantiating it. so, depending on whether you use wrong terminology, maybe, maybe not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been studying the code for a while and the only thing I could figure was that the issue is somehow linked to the use of contextmenu. It seems to me that variables are set back to their original when the menu action is supposed to be executed. Again, I am not too sure about that.

So, the only solution I found so far was to keep that vale in a "higher" context:
When I can still read the value,

```
getActivity().getIntent().putExtra(HomeActivity.ID_ENTRY, curMbr.getId_());
```

When I want to use it,

```
final String mbrID = getActivity().getIntent().getStringExtra(HomeActivity.ID_ENTRY);
```